# transfer data via USB port

Tags: android, usb, serial-port, fpga

Can I transfer a sequence of data(not file) from an Android device to a FPGA board via USB port? Does android support such transfers sequentially using some APIs?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your Android hardware there are up to three different ways of doing this. From most widely supported to least, they are the ADB protocol, USB Accessory mode, and USB Host mode. The ADB protocol was actually designed for debugging Android devices, but Android supports tunneling TCP connections over it and various projects such as [microbridge](http://code.google.com/p/microbridge/) have used this to stream data between Android applications and external hardware. Someone else has already linked the documentation for the other two.

Which of those you can actually use depends kind of FPGA board are you using and what kind of USB hardware it has. (I'm assuming for the moment that you're using an off-the-shelf board.) Some boards only have a USB-to-JTAG interface, generally something proprietary and undocumented, in which case USB Host is the only way of interfacing with it and you'll need some fairly ugly code on the Android end. Others, like the OsciPrime and Ztex's boards, use a Cypress FX2 microcontroller which again requires USB Host support but lets you define your own USB protocol between the two. A few have a Philips ISP1362 chip and support USB host mode, in which case you can use ADB or the Open Accessory Protocol - you might even be able to [boot ucLinux on it and connect to your phone with libusb](http://www.alterawiki.com/wiki/USBHost).

If you're developing your own hardware, it obviously depends on personal taste, performance requirements, the tradeoff between BOM costs and development time, and how wide a range of Android devices you need to be able to support. For example, the TUSB110x range of USB transceivers are dirt-cheap and can support USB Host mode, so in theory you can interface to basically all Android hardware in existence with them, but they require a lot of work on the FPGA side.

(This answer has had some hyperlinks culled due to the two-hyperlink limit for new users. Apologies.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Android device. 
Sinvce API level 12, Android developers have had [USB Host and USB accessory support](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html). 
USB accessory is a little funky as far as I can tell in that it is designed to only recognise an Android proprietary extension to the USB standard ["Android Open Accessory protocol"](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/aoa.html),

Take a look at the work done by the [Nexus Computing guys in Switzerland](http://android.serverbox.ch/)

In particular you will find blog posts regarding their [osciprime open source oscilloscope](http://www.osciprime.com/) which includes hardware interfacing with a XiLinx CPLD which is at least close to what you are trying to do.